# Diffeomorphism group of the unit circle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, circles, homotopy-theory

I am given to understand that the group of diffeomorphisms of the unit circle, $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^1)$, has two connected components, $\operatorname{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$ and $\operatorname{Diff}^-(\mathbb{S}^1)$, the diffeomorphisms that preserve or reverse the canonical (counterclockwise) orientation, respectively.

**Question 1**: How does one prove that?

**Question 2**: Given $\Phi, \Psi \in \operatorname{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S^1})$, can one construct an explicit path joining them?

I'd be satisfied already with a proof that we can join $\Psi, \Phi \in \operatorname{Diff}^+ (\mathbb{S}^1)$, without giving the path explicitly. I tried the obvious path, $t \mapsto \dfrac{t\Phi + (1-t)\Psi}{|t\Phi + (1-t)\Psi|}$, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how relevant it is, but in case anyone is wondering, consider the compact-open topology on $Diff(\mathbb{S}^1)$.

Comment: It is enough to connect everything in the positive part to the identity. To do that, pick a diffeo and lift it to a map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. *Then* interpolate with a map given by a translation. Then descend back to the circle.

Comment: @Leandro It seems pretty relevant!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Question 2:*

As Mariano points out, we can lift $\Phi \in \operatorname{Diff}^+{(\mathbb S^1)}$ uniquely to a diffeomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(0) \in [0,1)$ and $\phi(x+1) = \phi(x) + 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Lift $\Psi$ similarly to $\psi$. For $t \in [0,1]$ the map $\gamma_t = (1-t) \phi + t\psi$ is a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (it is strictly monotonically increasing because $ \gamma_{t}^\prime(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $t \in [0,1]$) such that $\gamma_t(0) \in [0,1)$ and $\gamma_t(x+1) = \gamma_t(x)+1$. Thus $\gamma_t$ descends to a diffeomorphism $\Gamma_t \in \operatorname{Diff}^+(\mathbb{S}^1)$, $\Gamma_0 = \Phi$ and $\Gamma_1=\Psi$. It is straightforwad to check that $t \mapsto \Gamma_t$ is a continuous path.

What we exploited here is that we have a short exact sequence (in fact a central extension)
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \operatorname{Diff}_{\mathbb{Z}}{(\mathbb{R})} \to \operatorname{Diff}^+{(\mathbb{S}^1)} \to 1
$$
where $\operatorname{Diff}_{\mathbb{Z}}{(\mathbb{R})}$ denotes the group of diffeomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ commuting with the shift $\tau(x) = x+1$ and $\mathbb{Z} = \langle \tau \rangle$ and the lift $\Phi \mapsto \phi$ is a section of this central extension.

*Question 1:*

It is clear that a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ either preserves or reverses orientation and that the orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms $\operatorname{Diff}^+{(\mathbb{S}^1)}$ form a normal subgroup of $\operatorname{Diff}{(\mathbb{S}^1)}$. Now simply use the conjugation diffeomorphism $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ to see that $\operatorname{Diff}^+{(\mathbb{S}^1)}$ has index 2.

---

For an excellent introduction to $\operatorname{Homeo}^+{(\mathbb{S}^1)}$ and $\operatorname{Diff}^+{(\mathbb{S}^1)}$ and their subgroups I recommend [Étienne Ghys](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/home/)'s article
*[Groups acting on the circle](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupsacting.pdf)*, Enseign. Math. (2) 47 (2001), no. 3–4, 329–407, [MR2111644](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/reviews/groupsacting-rev.pdf). The short exact sequence mentioned above plays a central rôle in the theory.

For more on the diffeomorphism group of the circle, I recommend consulting the work of [Andrés Navas](http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/author/A.Navas), and, of course, the classic article:

Michael R. Herman, *[Sur la conjugaison différentiable des difféomorphismes du cercle à des rotations](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1979__49__5_0)*, Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS, **49** (1979), p. 5–233.

Comment: Excellent answer, and I'll certainly look up those references. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does $0$ mean in your exact sequence?

Comment: @Alexei: $0$ as $0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is the neutral element and can be identified with the trivial group.

Comment: @t.b. Can you tell me please what is the tangent space of $\mathrm{Diff}^+(\mathbb S^1)$ at, let's say the identity map? Is it the same as for the whole group of diffeomorphisms? I look on $\mathrm{Diff}^+(\mathbb S^1)$ as on an infinite-dimensional Lie group. Thanks?

Comment: The links to the Ghys paper seem to be dead now.

Comment: @t.b. FYI All the links in your post are broken...

Comment: The Ghys article can be found here http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/groupscircle.pdf

Comment: Just to note, the link to Andrés Navas's author page at `front.math.ucdavis.edu` is currently broken, since the UC Davis front end of arXiv is down.