# Space of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms on the circle.

Tags: dynamical-systems, diffeomorphism

Diff$_+(\mathbb{T})$ is the space of orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms on the circle. Then is it true that it is connected?

I have looked through the similar questions on here, but seem to find no clear motivation, so far by reading through the sources of some of the post I have concluded that this statement is true. But I cannot seem to find any good motivation as to why.

If somebody could please refer me to a text where this is shown or describe it that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: given two diffeomorphisms, lift them to the fundamental group of the circle, and continuously deform one to the other there.

Comment: I misspoke above; I meant the _universal covering space_ of the circle.

Comment: I think I almost get it, I previously looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88386/diffeomorphism-group-of-the-unit-circle and I think that the same applies here although I think one cannot use the same map. So one has to find a map that is derived from $\mathbb{T}$? And I was wondering what that map would be in that case.

Comment: Question 2 in the link you provided in your previous comment is exactly the same as your question, and the accepted answer there exactly answers your question.

Comment: It is also a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2854031,